# Why is my furnace blowing hot air outside?

Tags: heating, furnace, venting

So I have been having trouble heating my home.  I noticed today that there is a vent blowing hot air outside. It is not the return, chimney or venting. Any ideas other that the builder thought we should all play our part in global climate control?

Comment: Do you mean that one of your air ducts leading from the furnace goes to the outside of your house? If so, I don't think any of us can answer 'why' it was done that way. It does seem illogical.

Comment: Sounds like you need an HVAC expert who knows the brand of equipment in to have a look and make sure it was properly installed.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a vent, or an exhaust fan from a bathroom or something?

Comment: Either your installer is an idiot or that's the combustion exhaust pipe.

Answer (score 3):

All gas furnaces require a flue to exhaust carbon monoxide outdoors, the reason modern units require a fan to do it is due to  the circuitous design of modern heat exchangers that extract more heat from the unit before exhausting it outdoors, natural  venting will no longer happen if the induced draft motor is not running, So much heat is removed these days they can be vented using PVC flue rather than metal and  moisture condenses making an acidic condensate that is drained just like the AC condensate is.
It is normal,if it were not so you would/ could die by operating the unit in that condition.